# apt update fails after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, official-repositories

After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 I get errors when I run apt-update.
Here's the output:

```
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I looked everywhere and tried everything but I can't fix this.
For example, I tried switching mirrors and moving the trusted.gpg file, nothing worked.

Comment: Are you *sure* your upgrade had no errors?

Comment: The upgrade had errors, I think while updating the kernel. Then I managed to manually install a kernel and complete the upgrade. The system boots and almost everything works, except apt and samba.

Comment: Addtional information belongs in the Question, clearly labelled as an UPDATE. Please don't bury important information in comments.

Comment: Try using dpkg to reinstall the `apt` package.

Comment: After thoroughly troubleshooting in the ubuntu IRC chat I couldn't fix it, so I simply decided to reinstall it.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem after upgrading to 18.04.1 Bionic. Also caused settings, VLC and sources to not work for me.

The problem was that gpg libraries were pointing towards libraries in /usr/local/lib rather than the default. Probably from some old install way back.

The solution for me was to move all of the GPG-related libraries in /usr/local/lib elsewhere, and re-do the links.

You can check what your gpg library linkages are by doing a:

```
sudo ldd /usr/bin/gpg
```

The fix entailed issuing the following commands on my machine:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo mkdir bkp
sudo mv libgcrypt* bkp
sudo mv libassuan* bkp
sudo mv libgpg* bkp
sudo ldconfig /usr/bin/gpg
```

That fixed all my problems.

Might be too late for the original poster, but figured I would post this solution in case anyone else runs into the issue.

Comment: I have same problem, not able to update or install anything as I cannot run apt-update. After your suggestion to check for gpg libraries location, I got this https://pastebin.com/6nq3UWjs, not sure is the same as you.

Comment: my libraries are different as your as trying to move them with your regex, bash cannot find them

Comment: Actually i found that my error is completely something different. When run the apt-udpate it fails because a package that I installed previousĺy does not have a release file( cronopete ).

Comment: I actually fix the issue installing again cronopete following this : https://www.ostechnix.com/cronopete-apples-time-machine-clone-linux/