# "Unknown error executing apt-key"

Tags: apt, updates, keyrings

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit: when I try to update I get the error: "Unknown error executing apt-key" several times, see the output below (I am not allowed to include the full screen dump because it contains too many links).

I have another computer with exactly the same configuration and OS that also uses the mirror at mirror.transip.net without this error, so I think that the mirror is not part of the problem.

It looks like a GPG error, but the keys look quite OK. To be sure, I deleted them and re-installed them using

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys [keyID]
```

Of course, I Googled around but I could not find a solution. None of the problem descriptions and diagnostics (such as in [[apt update fails after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065373/apt-update-fails-after-upgrade-to-18-04])) apply to mine.

I would be grateful for any suggestion!

Regards, Paul.

```
$ sudo apt update  
Hit:1 http://mirror.transip.net/ubuntu/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://mirror.transip.net/ubuntu/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://mirror.transip.net/ubuntu/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:1 http://mirror.transip.net/ubuntu/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
...
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://mirror.transip.net/ubuntu/ubuntu bionic InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
```